# Create a valid RSS feed using RABL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rabl

Is it possible to create a valid RSS feed using [RABL](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl)?

Or are there any walkthroughs showing how to set that up?

Here's what I'm ultimately trying to output is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title>My Stuff</title>
    <description>A description about this feed</description>
    <link>http://example.com/feed.rss</link>
    <item>
      <title>Article Title</title>
      <description>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit.</description>
      <pubDate>Thu, 13 Oct 2011 15:20:00 +0000</pubDate>
      <link>http://example.com/article/123</link>
      <guid>http://example.com/article/123</guid>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>Another Article</title>
      <description>Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</description>
      <pubDate>Thu, 13 Oct 2011 07:17:00 +0000</pubDate>
      <link>http://example.com/article/123</link>
      <guid>http://example.com/article/123</guid>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>Yep Another</title>
      <description>Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</description>
      <pubDate>Thu, 13 Oct 2011 05:48:00 +0000</pubDate>
      <link>http://example.com/article/123</link>
      <guid>http://example.com/article/123</guid>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using builder or some other XML generator for RSS feeds. It is all about using the right tool for the job: http://railscasts.com/episodes/87-generating-rss-feeds